# fstab mount doesn't find device

Tags: mount, ext4, fstab, alpine-linux

I have a problem with mounting a simple ext4 USB device with `sync` option and `defaults`.

This is my fstab entry:

```
UUID=233b8055-d596-48a7-a666-1e10b8860d9c /USBSSD sync 0 0
```

when I use `mount -a`, it says:

```
mount: mounting /dev/sdb on /USBSSD failed: No such device
```

Clearly you can see, that the UUID is resolved in /dev/sdb

However it says, that there is no such device.

It works when I manually mount it like that:

```
mount UUID=233b8055-d596-48a7-a666-1e10b8860d9c -o sync /USBSSD
```

Maybe anyone knows, what the problem might be here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that's right! I forgot the type! Thank you much for the `hint`. So sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 2):

The fields should be:

```
<filesystem> <mountpoint> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
```

Your problematic fstab entry omits `<type>`, this is the problem. Add the missing field:

```
UUID=233b8055-d596-48a7-a666-1e10b8860d9c /USBSSD ext4 sync 0 0
```